# Read Unreal Blueprint Output Pin names from c++?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal

I am trying to read the in/out execution pin names (the ones you can set in the details of the "inputs" node) from c++. is there a function or library that can help me do this? Or is it impossible to read blueprint nodes this way?

I have been scouring the internet and documentation for days now and am no closer to finding the solution. Thus I just want to ask someone more knowledgeable if it's even possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Improperly formatted questoins are likely to attract heavy downvoting. Think carefully if you need to include images ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) are useful to read). If you do include images, include them in the question, not just link to them.